# How do I determine move position of movie clip from specific number?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a 30 movice clip.I want to put movie clips in order.

Let say

```
if(number1==17){
        firstclip=rabbit;
       rabit.x = firstpositionx
      rabit.y = firstpositiony
    }
```

Or

```
  if(number2==17){
            secondclip=rabbit;
           rabit.x = secondpositionx
          rabit.y = secondpositiony
        }
```

I have 30 position and 30 movie clip.Each movie clip has must one position.İf I try this way or use switch,that means I have to write all possibilities.How I can do that with easier way ?

```
    var firstpositionx:Number=120;
var firstpositiony:Number=109;

var secondpositionx:Number=140;
var secondpositiony:Number=109;

var movieclipsArray:Array=new Array();
var posX:Array=new Array(firstpositionx,secondpositionx);
var posY:Array=new Array(firstpositiony,secondpositiony);

for(var i:int = 17; i < 30; i++)
{
   if(i==17){

movieclipsArray[i] = rabbit;
   rabbit.x = posX[i];
   rabbit.y = posY[i];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
// create 30 x positions for your objects
var xPositions = new Array(50, 100, 150, 200 ...);

// create 30 y positions for your objects
var yPositions = new Array(10, 60, 110, 160...);

for(var i:int = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    yourClip = new YourClip();
    addChild(yourClip);

    yourClip.x = xPositions[i];
    yourClip.y = yPositions[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but locations of clips are specified.Not rondom.

Comment: @KucuKeko I have updated the answer, make sure you add exactly 30 numbers in xPositions and yPositions arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
var movieclipsArray:Array=new Array():
var posX:Array=new Array(firstpositionx,secondpositionx.......);
var posY:Array=new Array(firstpositiony,secondpositiony.......);

for(var i:int = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
   if(i==17){

movieclipsArray[i] = rabbit;
   rabit.x = posX[i];
   rabit.y = posY[i];
 }
}
```

Comment: Movie clip just stuck top left corner.I have a as file and I give number from there.So how should I change " var i ". I updated first post.